# :dependent => :destroy on postgresql uuid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I've a Rails 4 app that uses Postgresql database. I'm using UUIDs as id for my models.

Everything works as expected, I'm trying to set a dependant destroy has many relation, and the "dependant destroy" is not working.

Is there any incompativility between postgress UUIDs and dependent destroy? I need to set foreign keys?

I expalin a bit of my code:

Navigation through models is working correclty

To define the has_many I'm using
`has_many :some_models, dependent: :destroy`

My migrations are something like:

```
def change
    create_table :my_model, id: :uuid  do |t|
```

To test, I'm using console. I create a relation, delete the "some_models" and the main model is not deleted.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking of the association backwards.  `dependent: destroy` means:  When I destroy a parent record, destroy the children that are associated with that record.  Here's a contrived example:

```
class User
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
end
```

When the user is deleted, you want their photos to also be deleted.

If you really want to delete a parent record when a child is deleted, you can do so from the `before_destroy` callback like so:

```
class Photo
  before_destroy :delete_parent_user

  def delete_parent_user
    user.destroy if self.user
  end
end
```

Note that other children may still be pointing to that parent record if this is a `has_many` relationship so this may not be advisable.

Comment: My question was not well writen (awnsers point to another direction that what I was looking for). I leave this as a correct answser but I've created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581756/dependent-destroy-not-working

Answer (score 0):

`dependent: :destroy` only destroys child records. When you destroy `my_model` record, all `some_model` records belonging to it will be destroyed.