# dependent destroy not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to use dependent: :destroy without success.

Lets put a simple example. I create a simple application with the following:

```
rails g model parent
rails g model child parent:references
```

Add following lines to parent.rb

```
has_many :children, dependent: :destroy
```

I do the following test in rails console (rails c)

```
p = Parent.create!
c = Child.create!
c.parent = p
c.save
#check association
Child.first == Child.first.parent.children.first
p.delete
#This should return 0
Child.count == 0
```

And Child.count returns 1.

What I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: You need to do `p.destroy`..

Comment: To enforce the object's before_destroy and after_destroy callbacks or any :dependent association options, use #destroy: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-delete

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[4.2.2.4 :dependent](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference)

If you set the `:dependent` option to:

- `:destroy`, when the object is destroyed, `#destroy` will be called on its associated objects.
- `:delete`, when the object is destroyed, all its associated objects *will be deleted directly* from the database *without* calling their `#destroy` method.

As per your settings, you have to do `p.destroy`.

[The `:dependent`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) option can have different values which specify how the deletion is done. For more information, see the documentation for this option on the different specific association types. When *no option is given*, the behaviour is to do nothing with the associated records when destroying a record.

For `has_many`, `destroy` and `destroy_all` will always call the `destroy` method of the record(s) being removed so that callbacks are run. However `delete` and `delete_all` will either do the deletion according to the *strategy* specified by the `:dependent` option, or if no `:dependent` option is given, then it will follow the default strategy. The default strategy is `:nullify` (**set the foreign keys to nil**), except for `has_many :through`, where the default strategy is `delete_all` (delete the join records, without running their callbacks).

Comment: Thank you so much, this was a time saver!

Answer (score 6):

Calling the `delete` method on an ActiveRecord derived object will issue a direct `DELETE` statement do the database, skipping any ActiveRecord callbacks and configurations such as `dependent: destroy`.

I believe you want the `destroy` method.

You could also set up a foreign key in the database and set it to cascade on delete, it might make sense, depending on your needs.