# How to delete records from Active Storage Blobs table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am using Active Storage to save attachments. My model look like this

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :avatar, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Every thing is working great, I am able to save avatar and delete avatar. When I delete avatar using following command `User.first.avatar.purge` then it deletes record from `active_storage_attachments` and `active_storage_blobs` table. Which is great. But when I delete all Users using following command `User.destroy_all` then it only delete record from `active_storage_attachments` table and it doesn't delete record from `active_storage_blobs` table.

So my question is how to delete records from `active_storage_blobs` table when using commands like `User.destroy_all`?

I use `User.destroy_all` a lot during testing and I have to manually delete records form `active_storage_blobs` table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dependent destroy not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581756/dependent-destroy-not-working)

Comment: `has_many_attached` defaults to `dependent: :purge_later`. If you want to purge the records immediately use `has_many_attached(dependent: :purge)`. https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/Model.html#method-i-has_many_attached

Comment: @max didn't work. I just tested it, it only deletes records from `active_storage_attachments` and not from `active_storage_blobs`

Comment: While I agree @max's solution should work, since you are saying it does not you could add a hook for `before_destroy { avatar_blob.destroy}`

Comment: @engineersmnky didn't work. still same problem.

Comment: Ran into almost identical issue, `has_one_attached` was not being purged on destroy but purging it manually was working fine. AS @max has mentioned above, it defaults to `purge_later`. Since its asynchronous, in my case I realized it was using the `default` queue for purging. Changed the queue to test in my case `config.active_storage.queues.purge = "name of queue"` and it worked. You can check if the queuing backend has a queue by the name of `default`.